# Problem making multisig PSBT on walletcreatefundedpsbt

Tags: bitcoin-cli, bip174-psbt

I'm fighting with PSBT to do a 2: 2 multisig with bitcoin-cli on testnet. Those are the steps I follow:

- Create a multisig with bitcoin-cli createmultisig 2 "["pubkey1", "pubkey2"]"
- Create the psbt with createpsbt:

  bitcoin-cli createpsbt '[{"txid": "578b667a5b2498bce06cf4b31e027a5a045af321f2465d3a7d8f302ac61759e6", "vout": 1 }, { "txid": "237bda433527d32ddce8da640e96efcbf3fddc1fbde8add362abe197cc3c151f", "vout": 0 }]' '{"data": "49879816ffbca992d07559d56c0cb8cbc14aa7eb896bc79f532d272595b5906f", "tb1q369frc2yk5vfly8ya57ed2qr7p3jef6fzaqyz6": 0.00009500 }'
- On one signer, call to walletprocesspsbt: bitcoin-cli walletprocesspsbt $psbt
- If I call here to analyzepsbt $psbt, this is what I get:

```
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "has_utxo": true,
      "is_final": false,
      "next": "updater",
      "missing": {
        "redeemscript": "e6b13137de705c19718f1aaf6f80709a9e6c1a7c"
      }
    },
    {
      "has_utxo": true,
      "is_final": false,
      "next": "updater",
      "missing": {
        "redeemscript": "e6b13137de705c19718f1aaf6f80709a9e6c1a7c"
      }
    }
  ],
  "fee": 0.00000500,
  "next": "updater"
}
```

To add the redeemscript it says is missing, ¿can I use walletcreatefundedpsbt? I try this:

```
bitcoin-cli walletcreatefundedpsbt '[{"txid": "578b667a5b2498bce06cf4b31e027a5a045af321f2465d3a7d8f302ac61759e6", "vout": 1, "scriptPubKey": "a914e6b13137de705c19718f1aaf6f80709a9e6c1a7c87", "witnessScript": "5221021efcdb8d9afb724ae7c58a3886656b56e3311e26f80a1d88e5f1f49e04d30d4b210345beb99ed5fd6ecad0e4a26b797b604495ebf85630c34e126a83c110b76dffdd52ae","amount":0.00005000}, {"txid": "237bda433527d32ddce8da640e96efcbf3fddc1fbde8add362abe197cc3c151f", "vout": 0, "scriptPubKey": "a914e6b13137de705c19718f1aaf6f80709a9e6c1a7c87", "witnessScript": "5221021efcdb8d9afb724ae7c58a3886656b56e3311e26f80a1d88e5f1f49e04d30d4b210345beb99ed5fd6ecad0e4a26b797b604495ebf85630c34e126a83c110b76dffdd52ae","amount":0.00005000}]'  '[{"data": "49879816ffbca992d07559d56c0cb8cbc14aa7eb896bc79f532d272595b5906f"}, {"tb1q369frc2yk5vfly8ya57ed2qr7p3jef6fzaqyz6": 0.00009500 }']
```

but I get "Insufficient funds" (error -4) ¿What I' missing or put it wrong on walletcreatefundedpsbt command?

Thank you very much! :-D

Answer (score 3):

> Create a multisig with bitcoin-cli createmultisig 2 "["pubkey1", "pubkey2"]"

Here is your problem. `createmultisig` is a utility function that only computes the multisig address. It doesn't store or otherwise add that address to your wallet. As a result, when you invoke `walletprocesspsbt` to update/sign, the wallet has no idea what that address is, or how to sign for it.

You want to use `addmultisigaddress` instead.

> To add the redeemscript it says is missing, can I use walletcreatefundedpsbt?

`walletcreatefundedpsbt` is an RPC to construct a PSBT from scratch; it's an alternative to the more manual `createpsbt` call, not a way to update an existing PSBT. You need to use `walletprocesspsbt` PSBT for that, but as I said, you first need to teach the wallet about the address you're using.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is your problem. createmultisig is a utility function that only
> computes the multisig address. It doesn't store or otherwise add that
> address to your wallet. As a result, when you invoke walletprocesspsbt
> to update/sign, the wallet has no idea what that address is, or how to
> sign for it.
>
> You want to use addmultisigaddress instead.

I try with

```
bitcoin-cli addmultisigaddress 2 "[\"02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521\",\"035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c629349\"]"

{
  "address": "tb1qvj2w46y4cx0kjdsnep4ajt6gclreatvwwawazzyw2gqklwaakgzs8l24zr",
  "redeemScript": "522102861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d21652121035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c62934952ae",
  "descriptor": "wsh(multi(2,[ac6d6edb/0'/0'/2']02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521,[9e497453]035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c629349))#cpxsl54h"
}
```

I send some coins to this address. If I do:

```
bitcoin-cli listunspent 0 99999 [\"tb1qvj2w46y4cx0kjdsnep4ajt6gclreatvwwawazzyw2gqklwaakgzs8l24zr\"]
[]
```

Empty. I need to importaddress to appear some UTXOs inside listunspent. I import address using this command:

```
bitcoin-cli importaddress "tb1qvj2w46y4cx0kjdsnep4ajt6gclreatvwwawazzyw2gqklwaakgzs8l24zr" "multisig" false
```

*When you say "It doesn't store or otherwise add that address to your wallet". ¿If you see inside listunspent the UTXO associated with this address, I'm ok with PSBT to can fill the data it needs?*

(have an update that fix the problem)

I create psbt with the command in my question, with importaddress I have the utxos associated with the multisig, I walletprocesspsbt with the first signer. This is what I get:

```
bitcoin-cli decodepsbt cHNidP8BAKYCAAAAAhXi9txucDKfTt7mXCZsKa0hsjgsLoq5YZGaUuwN6jbOAAAAAAD/////sB0o0i9FetuvOvL44+4tfHB2BP/1Dq0dtBopnDuTUV0AAAAAAP////8CAAAAAAAAAAAiaiBJh5gW/7ypktB1WdVsDLjLwUqn64lrx59TLScllbWQb85KAAAAAAAAFgAUm/7/n/VJl/i0rBrmlSFsZ/NozEYAAAAAAAEAXgIAAAABsB0o0i9FetuvOvL44+4tfHB2BP/1Dq0dtBopnDuTUV0BAAAAAP7///8B6iQAAAAAAAAiACBklOrolcGfaTYTyGvZL0jHx56tjndd0QiOUgFvu72yBZj+GwABASvqJAAAAAAAACIAIGSU6uiVwZ9pNhPIa9kvSMfHnq2Od13RCI5SAW+7vbIFIgIChh+z4stjgW+oAZUTzqC9kx1MFTDjJhtGarl4jX0hZSFHMEQCID6mV3QiDUPp6EIweaenZx3kkHU1bro8nQn1PSmRt2ZFAiAxAlJ1OPtiw0lJNQ/VkbZOZ+s/onDRWC3nRAvAMvMorgEBBUdSIQKGH7Piy2OBb6gBlRPOoL2THUwVMOMmG0ZquXiNfSFlISEDUzOtNV523d7M5VFLmpmfTsMAL5oAgzt7D8+8SVxik0lSriIGAoYfs+LLY4FvqAGVE86gvZMdTBUw4yYbRmq5eI19IWUhEKxtbtsAAACAAAAAgAIAAIAiBgNTM601Xnbd3szlUUuamZ9OwwAvmgCDO3sPz7xJXGKTSQSeSXRTAAEApgIAAAACIfcY2yOhSRdNWwkluhcrdfnpZBjNkEzbBSjuZi9EY98BAAAAAP7////m9ElqxQQEla0RvsRKc4C1Pm0eWijkItpm0NWmwqFtLgEAAAAA/v///wIQJwAAAAAAACIAIGSU6uiVwZ9pNhPIa9kvSMfHnq2Od13RCI5SAW+7vbIFNCYAAAAAAAAWABTmE28wyI0yfbWezbwt7AM5qC10qJj+GwABASsQJwAAAAAAACIAIGSU6uiVwZ9pNhPIa9kvSMfHnq2Od13RCI5SAW+7vbIFIgIChh+z4stjgW+oAZUTzqC9kx1MFTDjJhtGarl4jX0hZSFHMEQCIAcK7oIjvPK8bmtj/lYkERVWGArHkELHY3nm7SjpeK0XAiAjwUBJ5LNjjoY6ogXOYVHcsrIXhGtcQ35HL+qhK536iwEBBUdSIQKGH7Piy2OBb6gBlRPOoL2THUwVMOMmG0ZquXiNfSFlISEDUzOtNV523d7M5VFLmpmfTsMAL5oAgzt7D8+8SVxik0lSriIGAoYfs+LLY4FvqAGVE86gvZMdTBUw4yYbRmq5eI19IWUhEKxtbtsAAACAAAAAgAIAAIAiBgNTM601Xnbd3szlUUuamZ9OwwAvmgCDO3sPz7xJXGKTSQSeSXRTAAAiAgJgDXer7s2e/Bn+qUPtR+vziM9NkkvCozLNN/AZCCVd3xCsbW7bAAAAgAAAAIAEAACAAA==
{
  "tx": {
    "txid": "5fa020d46c8b64698b326d87635e212842889d2cca2bc23539b84321b6d90460",
    "hash": "5fa020d46c8b64698b326d87635e212842889d2cca2bc23539b84321b6d90460",
    "version": 2,
    "size": 166,
    "vsize": 166,
    "weight": 664,
    "locktime": 0,
    "vin": [
      {
        "txid": "ce36ea0dec529a9161b98a2e2c38b221ad296c265ce6de4e9f32706edcf6e215",
        "vout": 0,
        "scriptSig": {
          "asm": "",
          "hex": ""
        },
        "sequence": 4294967295
      },
      {
        "txid": "5d51933b9c291ab41dad0ef5ff0476707c2deee3f8f23aafdb7a452fd2281db0",
        "vout": 0,
        "scriptSig": {
          "asm": "",
          "hex": ""
        },
        "sequence": 4294967295
      }
    ],
    "vout": [
      {
        "value": 0.00000000,
        "n": 0,
        "scriptPubKey": {
          "asm": "OP_RETURN 49879816ffbca992d07559d56c0cb8cbc14aa7eb896bc79f532d272595b5906f",
          "hex": "6a2049879816ffbca992d07559d56c0cb8cbc14aa7eb896bc79f532d272595b5906f",
          "type": "nulldata"
        }
      },
      {
        "value": 0.00019150,
        "n": 1,
        "scriptPubKey": {
          "asm": "0 9bfeff9ff54997f8b4ac1ae695216c67f368cc46",
          "hex": "00149bfeff9ff54997f8b4ac1ae695216c67f368cc46",
          "reqSigs": 1,
          "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
          "addresses": [
            "tb1qn0l0l8l4fxtl3d9vrtnf2gtvvlek3nzxtrctvx"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "unknown": {
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "witness_utxo": {
        "amount": 0.00009450,
        "scriptPubKey": {
          "asm": "0 6494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
          "hex": "00206494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
          "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
          "address": "tb1qvj2w46y4cx0kjdsnep4ajt6gclreatvwwawazzyw2gqklwaakgzs8l24zr"
        }
      },
      "non_witness_utxo": {
        "txid": "ce36ea0dec529a9161b98a2e2c38b221ad296c265ce6de4e9f32706edcf6e215",
        "hash": "ce36ea0dec529a9161b98a2e2c38b221ad296c265ce6de4e9f32706edcf6e215",
        "version": 2,
        "size": 94,
        "vsize": 94,
        "weight": 376,
        "locktime": 1834648,
        "vin": [
          {
            "txid": "5d51933b9c291ab41dad0ef5ff0476707c2deee3f8f23aafdb7a452fd2281db0",
            "vout": 1,
            "scriptSig": {
              "asm": "",
              "hex": ""
            },
            "sequence": 4294967294
          }
        ],
        "vout": [
          {
            "value": 0.00009450,
            "n": 0,
            "scriptPubKey": {
              "asm": "0 6494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
              "hex": "00206494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
              "reqSigs": 1,
              "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
              "addresses": [
                "tb1qvj2w46y4cx0kjdsnep4ajt6gclreatvwwawazzyw2gqklwaakgzs8l24zr"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "partial_signatures": {
        "02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521": "304402203ea65774220d43e9e8423079a7a7671de49075356eba3c9d09f53d2991b7664502203102527538fb62c34949350fd591b64e67eb3fa270d1582de7440bc032f328ae01"
      },
      "witness_script": {
        "asm": "2 02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521 035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c629349 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
        "hex": "522102861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d21652121035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c62934952ae",
        "type": "multisig"
      },
      "bip32_derivs": [
        {
          "pubkey": "02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521",
          "master_fingerprint": "ac6d6edb",
          "path": "m/0'/0'/2'"
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c629349",
          "master_fingerprint": "9e497453",
          "path": "m"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "witness_utxo": {
        "amount": 0.00010000,
        "scriptPubKey": {
          "asm": "0 6494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
          "hex": "00206494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
          "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
          "address": "tb1qvj2w46y4cx0kjdsnep4ajt6gclreatvwwawazzyw2gqklwaakgzs8l24zr"
        }
      },
      "non_witness_utxo": {
        "txid": "5d51933b9c291ab41dad0ef5ff0476707c2deee3f8f23aafdb7a452fd2281db0",
        "hash": "5d51933b9c291ab41dad0ef5ff0476707c2deee3f8f23aafdb7a452fd2281db0",
        "version": 2,
        "size": 166,
        "vsize": 166,
        "weight": 664,
        "locktime": 1834648,
        "vin": [
          {
            "txid": "df63442f66ee2805db4c90cd1864e9f9752b17ba25095b4d1749a123db18f721",
            "vout": 1,
            "scriptSig": {
              "asm": "",
              "hex": ""
            },
            "sequence": 4294967294
          },
          {
            "txid": "2e6da1c2a6d5d066da22e4285a1e6d3eb580734ac4be11ad950404c56a49f4e6",
            "vout": 1,
            "scriptSig": {
              "asm": "",
              "hex": ""
            },
            "sequence": 4294967294
          }
        ],
        "vout": [
          {
            "value": 0.00010000,
            "n": 0,
            "scriptPubKey": {
              "asm": "0 6494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
              "hex": "00206494eae895c19f693613c86bd92f48c7c79ead8e775dd1088e52016fbbbdb205",
              "reqSigs": 1,
              "type": "witness_v0_scripthash",
              "addresses": [
                "tb1qvj2w46y4cx0kjdsnep4ajt6gclreatvwwawazzyw2gqklwaakgzs8l24zr"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "value": 0.00009780,
            "n": 1,
            "scriptPubKey": {
              "asm": "0 e6136f30c88d327db59ecdbc2dec0339a82d74a8",
              "hex": "0014e6136f30c88d327db59ecdbc2dec0339a82d74a8",
              "reqSigs": 1,
              "type": "witness_v0_keyhash",
              "addresses": [
                "tb1qucfk7vxg35e8mdv7ek7zmmqr8x5z6a9geyj9ae"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "partial_signatures": {
        "02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521": "30440220070aee8223bcf2bc6e6b63fe5624111556180ac79042c76379e6ed28e978ad17022023c14049e4b3638e863aa205ce6151dcb2b217846b5c437e472feaa12b9dfa8b01"
      },
      "witness_script": {
        "asm": "2 02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521 035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c629349 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
        "hex": "522102861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d21652121035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c62934952ae",
        "type": "multisig"
      },
      "bip32_derivs": [
        {
          "pubkey": "02861fb3e2cb63816fa8019513cea0bd931d4c1530e3261b466ab9788d7d216521",
          "master_fingerprint": "ac6d6edb",
          "path": "m/0'/0'/2'"
        },
        {
          "pubkey": "035333ad355e76dddecce5514b9a999f4ec3002f9a00833b7b0fcfbc495c629349",
          "master_fingerprint": "9e497453",
          "path": "m"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
    },
    {
      "bip32_derivs": [
        {
          "pubkey": "02600d77abeecd9efc19fea943ed47ebf388cf4d924bc2a332cd37f01908255ddf",
          "master_fingerprint": "ac6d6edb",
          "path": "m/0'/0'/4'"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fee": 0.00000300
}
```

I sign with the second signer.

```
 bitcoin-cli --datadir=/home/biteskola/.daniel walletprocesspsbt 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
{
  "psbt": "cHNidP8BAKYCAAAAAhXi9txucDKfTt7mXCZsKa0hsjgsLoq5YZGaUuwN6jbOAAAAAAD/////sB0o0i9FetuvOvL44+4tfHB2BP/1Dq0dtBopnDuTUV0AAAAAAP////8CAAAAAAAAAAAiaiBJh5gW/7ypktB1WdVsDLjLwUqn64lrx59TLScllbWQb85KAAAAAAAAFgAUm/7/n/VJl/i0rBrmlSFsZ/NozEYAAAAAAAEAXgIAAAABsB0o0i9FetuvOvL44+4tfHB2BP/1Dq0dtBopnDuTUV0BAAAAAP7///8B6iQAAAAAAAAiACBklOrolcGfaTYTyGvZL0jHx56tjndd0QiOUgFvu72yBZj+GwABASvqJAAAAAAAACIAIGSU6uiVwZ9pNhPIa9kvSMfHnq2Od13RCI5SAW+7vbIFAQjaBABHMEQCID6mV3QiDUPp6EIweaenZx3kkHU1bro8nQn1PSmRt2ZFAiAxAlJ1OPtiw0lJNQ/VkbZOZ+s/onDRWC3nRAvAMvMorgFHMEQCIF3e8YzHPjqTKkdZcBkSr1e/h0wBUJCdw2m+PzjnQWR1AiAxmh4Skd48VE5ioCUQSr/GS3n5e3EqoD/AEJNv603tGgFHUiEChh+z4stjgW+oAZUTzqC9kx1MFTDjJhtGarl4jX0hZSEhA1MzrTVedt3ezOVRS5qZn07DAC+aAIM7ew/PvElcYpNJUq4AAQCmAgAAAAIh9xjbI6FJF01bCSW6Fyt1+elkGM2QTNsFKO5mL0Rj3wEAAAAA/v///+b0SWrFBASVrRG+xEpzgLU+bR5aKOQi2mbQ1abCoW0uAQAAAAD+////AhAnAAAAAAAAIgAgZJTq6JXBn2k2E8hr2S9Ix8eerY53XdEIjlIBb7u9sgU0JgAAAAAAABYAFOYTbzDIjTJ9tZ7NvC3sAzmoLXSomP4bAAEBKxAnAAAAAAAAIgAgZJTq6JXBn2k2E8hr2S9Ix8eerY53XdEIjlIBb7u9sgUBCNoEAEcwRAIgBwrugiO88rxua2P+ViQRFVYYCseQQsdjeebtKOl4rRcCICPBQEnks2OOhjqiBc5hUdyysheEa1xDfkcv6qErnfqLAUcwRAIgPYTSLc5zz7sh2g6kKBhukRwGYIkWJGHRe8+3VYjTKswCIHhQKlV0qV5DXjuU9CqgXkulREaKKnDee8m+vu+xj7UFAUdSIQKGH7Piy2OBb6gBlRPOoL2THUwVMOMmG0ZquXiNfSFlISEDUzOtNV523d7M5VFLmpmfTsMAL5oAgzt7D8+8SVxik0lSrgAAIgICYA13q+7NnvwZ/qlD7Ufr84jPTZJLwqMyzTfwGQglXd8QrG1u2wAAAIAAAACABAAAgAA=",
  "complete": true
}
```

but now the signatures are missing:

```
bitcoin-cli analyzepsbt 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
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "has_utxo": true,
      "is_final": false,
      "next": "signer",
      "missing": {
        "signatures": [
          "9e497453046a2170505985012c40e447b24a0c9a"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "has_utxo": true,
      "is_final": false,
      "next": "signer",
      "missing": {
        "signatures": [
          "9e497453046a2170505985012c40e447b24a0c9a"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "estimated_vsize": 276,
  "estimated_feerate": 0.00001086,
  "fee": 0.00000300,
  "next": "signer"
}
```

I thought that using walletprocesspsbt among other things it signed the UTXOS.

Thank you very much! :-D

UPDATE1:

The signature missing was fixed combining both signatures:

```
bitcoin-cli combinepsbt '["signer1_psbt","signer2_psbt" ]'
```

https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/5fa020d46c8b64698b326d87635e212842889d2cca2bc23539b84321b6d90460?expand

*As I understand, one signer can createpsbt and walletprocesspsbt. The other signer make the same and then combine both psbt ¿right?*